# SVN patch file doesn't contain file renames?

Tags: svn, patch, ankhsvn

I used Ankh SVN to create a patch from my local working copy changes, so I could temporarily revert to the base version to test something out. Then I tried reapplying the patch, but that failed, because my changes had included some file renames, which apparently hadn't been reflected in the patch.

Can I make the patch know about file renames?

Answer (score 0):

Currently subversion can handle file rename meta information. For example, in tortoiseSvn you can "repair file renames" in the commit window.

But if you create a patch from renamed files and try to apply the patch, you come into trouble.

http://blog.matejzavrsnik.com/2011/10/subversion-problems-when-renaming-files-and-folders/